# Using onblur and setTimeout to close a sub menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout, onblur

I want to use onblur to close a sub-menu. I've got it to "hide" the sub-menu, but it does just that. I want the menu to go back to its original state. I would also like to set a timeout on the menu so it will close after 5-10 seconds.

P.S I tried to make a jsfiddle for this, and it didnt function. Also, this is for a mobile site.

HTML

```
<div class="smenu_div"">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="menu-title" href="#" onblur="hidemenu()" onclick="showsub()">Menu</a>
        <ul id='hiddenMenu'>
           <li><a href="/mobile/m.index.html">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="m.trucks.html">Trucks</a></li>
           <li><a href="m.equipment.hmtl">Equipment</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

CSS

```
.smenu_div ul
{

    padding:0px;
    margin-top:5px; 
    margin-right:40px;
    font-family:georgia;
    font-size:70px;
    color:#ffffff;
    list-style:none;
    text-indent:15px;
    text-align:center; 
    width:40%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float:right;
}

.smenu_div ul li
{

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    line-height:justified;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position:relative;
}


/* Changed this so that your hidden menu is hidden by default */
.smenu_div li ul
{ 

  z-index: 50;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  float:none;
  }

.smenu_div ul li a
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

/* @new */
.smenu_div ul li a.menu-title
{
    padding-right: 50px;
    background: #000000 url('plus.png') no-repeat right center;
    background-size: 75px 75px;

}


.menu-open .smenu_div ul li a.menu-title
{

   background-image: url('minus.png')
}
```

JavaScript

```
 var hidden = true;

    function showsub() {

        document.getElementById('hiddenMenu').style.display = (hidden) ? 'block' : 'none';
        document.body.classList.toggle('menu-open');
        hidden = !hidden;


    };

    function hidemenu() {
        document.getElementById('hiddenMenu').style.display =  'none';
        document.body.classList.toggle('plus');
        hidden = !hidden;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a mistake in your html code `<div class ="smenu_div"">` has one too many quotes, so it breaks jsfiddle.

You almost have it, literally all you're missing in code is

```
 setTimeout(hidemenu,10000);
```

from `showsub`. Note, if you want to prevent it from closing after 10s, if the user keeps pressing on stuff, you'll need some extra code, but if you're ok with it closing 10s after the user clicks on menu no matter what then it's ok.

[here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eBux/)

Comment: Alright. Got that. Now i updated the fiddle so you can see the plus and minus images i want. Play with the onBlur by clicking outside the menu. You can see that the minus stays minus when it should go back to plus. Is there a way to reload the menu, instead of hiding it.

http://jsfiddle.net/3eBux/2/

Comment: ok i got it. the click event works properly, but with the setTimeout you have no way to remove `menu-open`. I reworked the code slightly so that the toggle of `menu-open` respects what you are trying to do. (i.e. a call to `hidemenu` always removes `menu-open` but `showmenu` toggles based on `hidden`) [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eBux/3/)

Comment: Works great on a laptop. When i try it on my phone, the onBlur doesn't work. Is there a workaround for a touch-screen?

Comment: you could try attaching to onChange instead. onBlur will work for most mobiles, but it does have issues.